# twitter client javascript qml oauth 401 failed to validate signature and token

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, qml

I'm trying to code a javascript-qml based twitter client. 
I'm using oauth javascript library, advised by twitter dev page and 
hosted on google code. (http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/ 
javascript/) 
I've been trying to get the request token from twitter by doing what's 
said on twiter dev page, then by analysing oauth library example's 
(source code, http header and wireshark), but i've always failed "401 
- failed to validate oauth signature and token". 
I've tried a lot of different way to do it, by changing order of 
parameters before basestring and signing it, posting get parameters, 
setting header "Authorization" data, etc etc, but it's failed every 
time. 
I'm probably doing something dumb and wrong but i just can't see 
where. 
Here is my code :

```
function getSignature() {
var accessor = { consumerSecret: consumer_secret,
    tokenSecret: oauth_token_secret
};
var message = { method: "POST",
    action: request_token_url,
    parameters: []
};
message.parameters.push(["oauth_callback", OAuth.formEncode(oauth_callback)]);
message.parameters.push(["oauth_consumer_key", consumer_key]);
message.parameters.push(["oauth_nonce", OAuth.nonce(10)]);
message.parameters.push(["oauth_signature_method", signature_method]);
message.parameters.push(["oauth_timestamp", OAuth.timestamp()]);
OAuth.completeRequest(message, accessor);
OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
console.log(OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_signature"));
var data = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="+consumer_key+"&oauth_signature_method="+signature_method+"&oauth_callback="+OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_callback")
    +"&oauth_timestamp="+OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_timestamp")+"&oauth_nonce="+OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_nonce")+"&oauth_signature="+OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_signature");
console.log(data);
request_maker = new XMLHttpRequest();
request_maker.open("POST", request_token_url);
request_maker.setRequestHeader("Authorization", data);
request_maker.onreadystatechange = oth_func;
request_maker.send();
```

}

If anyone can help me ! It would be a relief ! 
Thx

Comment: FWIW, I've seen this issue when my URL parameters were not percent encoded and this might apply to header data as well, such as the consumer key. If it's an alternative to you, you could try the Qt library kQOAuth which has a working Twitter example.

Answer (score 0):

gaetan, since you're getting 401 error that sounds like you may be doing something wrong in terms of Twitter API or maybe even something with Java Script so I believe thats hardly a QML-related. But what I can recommend is to have a look at QML Twitter client that you can find in your qt source code director in demos/declarative/twitter. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: Barbaris, unfortunatly the example given in qml demos is just about search and doesn't show how to implement oauth protocol. I assume my mistake is in oauth signature or the way i call twitter's api, but i just can't find where.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because the time on my target (virtual) machine was a week out from the actual time. When I updated the time the problem went away.